# Как считать значения с датчиков набора Lego Mindstorms EV3 в Visual Studio 2017 на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Недавно, я решила программировать  блок EV3 на С++ в Visual Studio,подключила расширения Cpp4Robots для среды Microsoft Visual Studio, которое позволяет программировать роботов на родном языке C / C ++ и в среде разработки Microsoft Visual Studio. После подключения появилось меню для работы c EV3, в котором есть раздел "help" - документация для работы с датчиками и моторами.
Скажите, пожалуйста, знаете ли вы другие источники информации (или примеры готовых программ) для программирования EV3 в Visual Studio? В частности, у меня не получается работать с датчиками - считать с них значения.
Если знаете источники информации - отправьте, пожалуйста, ссылки.
Спасибо.

```
#include <EV3_LCDDisplay.h>
#include <EV3_Thread.h>
#include <EV3_Sensor_Ultrasonic.h>
#include <EV3_Motor.h>
#include "EV3_Sensor_UART.h"
#include "EV3_Sensor_Color.h"
using namespace ev3_c_api;

int main()
{
int a = GetColor(E_Port_1, E_Layer_1);

        if(a == 0) 
        {
        SpeedMotor(E_Port_AB, 50, E_Layer_1);
        EV3_Sleep(1000);
        }
        return 0;

}
```

Указан код, в котором я пыталась считать значение с датчика цвета. Ожидалось -  если цвет чёрный, значит  моторы будут  вращаться вперёд некоторое время. 
В реальности моторы вращаются постоянно, не обращая на поставленное условие.

Comment: Про какое условие Вы говорите?

Comment: if(a == 0) , я ошиблась в значении , должно быть if ( а==1) , так как 1 - это чёрный цвет

Comment: Исправьте код в примере, пожалуйста. Я так понимаю, что неудобства Вам доставляет команда `SpeedMotor`?

Answer (score 0):

Мне приходилось работать с EV3, только использовал я Python-библиотеки (или непосредственно работал с файлами в `/sys/class/*`) - поэтому, признаюсь, с используемым Вами API я не знаком.

Но, проводя аналогию между тем API которым пользовался я, и тем, которое используете Вы, могу предположить, что Вы или устанавливаете скорость (об/сек), или какое-то другое значение, вроде мощности/[скважности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Я не смог найти полноценной документации на API библиотек, поставляемых с плагином - она, вообще, имеется? Если да - поделитесь ссылкой, я постараюсь Вам помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <EV3_BrickUI.h>
#include <EV3_Thread.h>
#include <EV3_Motor.h>
#include <EV3_Sensor_Color.h>

using namespace ev3_c_api;

int EV3_main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        E_Color a = GetColor(E_Port_1);

        if ( a == E_Color_Black ) 
        {
            SpeedMotor(E_Port_AB, 50);
            EV3_Sleep(1000);
            StopMotor(E_Port_AB, true);
        }

        if ( isBrickButtonPressed(E_BTN_ESC) )
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```